# Accurate rowcount immediately after ANALYZE?

Tags: postgresql, performance

In a postgres database using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A
```

Can be time consuming, particularly on larger tables.

I know that a VACUUM ANALYZE will recover unused space and gather statistics on table usage. Do these statistics include an *accurate* rowcount? If so where do I find it? I also know that this query....

```
SELECT reltuples AS approximate_row_count FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table_name';
```

Will give an approximate row count, and the that value will be updated with an ANALYZE.

If I have exclusive access to a database and run this immediately after an ANALYZE will it be 100% accurate at that point? I've tried it on couple of very small tables and it does seem to match the results of SELECT COUNT(*).... but is this a technique I can rely on?

Comment: You might try another approach. Create trigger on the table on delete and insert, which decreases/increases a row counter. You can then read the counter for superfast rowcount.

Comment: Don't trust on it. Also note that different sessions could *see* a different `COUNT()`